# liquibase Element 'databaseChangeLog' used but not declared

Tags: xml-parsing, liquibase

We use liquibase 3.6.1 for change database mysql 5.x.

On Windows (10) everything is working. But on linux we get the error:

```
liquibase.exception.ChangeLogParseException: Error parsing line 2 column 19 
of /home/myapp/conf/db/liquibase/changelog.xml: Element 
'databaseChangeLog' used but not declared.
    at    
 liquibase.parser.core.xml.XMLChangeLogSAXParser.parseToNode
Caused by: oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLParseException: Element 
'databaseChangeLog' used but not declared.
at oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLError.flushErrors(XMLError.java:143)
 oracle.xml.parser.v2.NonValidatingParser.parseDocument 
(NonValidatingParser.java:269)
at oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:149) 
at liquibase.parser.core.xml.XMLChangeLogSAXParser.parseToNode
(XMLChangeLogSAXParser.java)
... 11 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: <Line 2, Column 19>: XML-0149: (Error) Element 'databaseChangeLog' used but not declared.
at oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLError.flushErrorHandler(XMLError.java:169)
at oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLError.flushErrors(XMLError.java:137)
... 14 common frames omitted
```

Probably the problem is connected with xml parser, but I don't understand what really is happening. And what can I do.

Unfortunately, I also don't have access to the linux machine.

Answer (score 0):

It could be an encoding problem of your changelog files.

Ensure that your are in UTF-8 for safety

Comment: Thanks for advice. I'll try it